# Run a python program for a specific time

Tags: python

I wrote a web scraper in `python` which I want to run for a specific time. Say 1 minute and then kill it. I want to measure the performance of the program. Currently I am using `subprocess` module. I start the program from another script and count time.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", my_program, arguments])
```

After executing for specific time I kill it by it's process id.

```
child_pid = proc.pid
os.kill(child_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Is there a more efficient or elegant way to do this ?

Comment: You can make CMD or Terminal script to open a program waith for some time and then close it. If I were you I would to this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.Popen.terminate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) (SIGTERM) or [`subprocess.Popen.kill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) (SIGKILL) method:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", my_program, arguments])
...
proc.terminate()
```

BTW, if you want to use same python program you used to launch the program, use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable) instead of `"python"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there way to terminate the program from `my_program` and not using another script?

Comment: @salmanwahed, Without knowing the structure of `my_program`, I can't answer. Could you update the question or post a separated question with the content of the `my_program`?

Comment: I can not give the exact code. But here, `my_program` is a web scraper using Beautifulsoup. and It starts by calling a function `main()`. which in turns calls other function for web page scraping.

Comment: @salmanwahed, It's not enough. If the crawler is using a loop, before a loop remember the start time using something like `starttime = time.time()` and for each iteration, check elapsed time `time.time() - starttime`, `break` if time is over.

Comment: may be start a thread for counting time? I am not sure about this.

Comment: @salmanwahed, There's another way. Maybe this is what you want. Assume there's a program like this: http://pastebin.com/8W31mbRU, and here's a modified version that will terminate the program in 5 secons: http://pastebin.com/sAFw0pD8

Comment: @salmanwahed, Alternative way is to use [`signal.alarm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.alarm): http://pastebin.com/YYiYCxgj  (As you may know, UNIX only)

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I was looking for something like this. Would you explain this code in your answer? http://pastebin.com/YYiYCxgj

Comment: @salmanwahed, If you use `signal.alarm(5)`, system will deliver SIGALRM signal 5 seconds later. You can set handler for that signal.  Follow the link in my previous commnet, or manpage for alarm(2) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import Popen
from time import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", my_program, arguments])
time.sleep(60)
proc.terminate()
```